# How to transition from LaunchScreen to main page in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to programming with Swift. I wanted to know how to create an app from scratch (from the beginning as in with no launchscreen, no first page, and no storyboards) - I deleted all my ViewControllers and their associated storyboards along with the launch screen. I managed to get the splash screen working but I am unable to make it transition to the first page (also currently present).

Things I have done:
Created new storyboard containing main page's view controller and associated swift file extending UIViewController. Also linked the two.

But I cannot get the lauchscreen to transition to the main page. Any help with this would be most appreciated. I also tried comparing with other Swift projects but I do not know how to proceed.

Edit:

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

That's my view controller for the main page. My story boards are extremely basic and have no ui elements in them, just a view controller. The question has been answered by @nobre.

Comment: Depends on how you made your transition to the LaunchScreen, can you add more information to your question, for instance the code you had written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must point your target's `Main Interface` to your Storyboard.
[image]

In code you would have to, in the `AppDelegate`, create an `UIWindow` instance with frame set to `NSScreen.mainScreen.bounds`, create your view controller programmatically, set your controller as the window's `rootViewController`, then call `makeKeyAndVisible` on the window.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like there's a lot more to learn about the IDE, apologies if the question was too basic.